# Why wget backticks shell command works in PHP CLI and not in a PHP script?

Tags: php, shell, wget, shell-exec

just for fun I am trying to make wget downloads from php cli (/usr/bin/php -a) and it works:

```
php > `wget -q -nd -O /Users/user/path/to/file.html http:\/\/host.com/some_file.html`;
php > // a HTML file is downloaded and its content is placed into /Users/user/path/to/file.html
```

However, when I try to do the same thing from a PHP script, it does not work:

```
<?php 
 `wget -q -nd -O /Users/user/path/to/file.html http:\/\/host.com/some_file.html`;
 // After requesting the script from the browser and after the script is executed, the file doesn't exist on the specified path
```

I would like to say that the user which executes apache and therefore PHP server side scripting is the same as the user which executes the php command from the command line (so I guess this should not be a problem of permissions).

Why if I use a .php script and call wget inside the script the file is not saved?

Thanks for the attention!

PS: please, do not tell me that I can use curl for such a task, I know I can, I am just curious to know how can I do something similar without using PHP tools, that's it

Comment: Are there any errors in the PHP log?

Comment: Maybe `wget` isn't in the `$PATH` of the apache user?

Comment: @Barmar No there isn't any error in the php error log, I have checked `wget` should be in the path because the apache user is the same user I use to run `php` CLI command

Comment: The daemon probably doesn't run the shell startup scripts `.profile` and `.bashrc`, which are where environment variables are usually set. So even if it's the same userid, the environment won't be the same.

Comment: Maybe you have `safe_mode` enabled? That disables backticks. Does `shell_exec` work?

Comment: No, safe_mode is enabled, cause if I do a `whoami` or `pwd` I can echo the output, I guess this is the problem: I have wget installed with HomeBrew (I use OS X) inside `/opt/local/bin/wget`. The `/opt/local/bin/` is added to the $PATH env variable inside my .bash_profile file, which is loaded whenever I open the Terminal.app. As I am executing the shell command from PHP, .bash_profile is not executed, so I end with a very lean $PATH environment variable (`/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin` if I output the $PATH variable from the PHP script), and the shell doesn't find the wget command.

Comment: This has worked for me: `<?php
\`cd ~ && pwd && . .bash_profile && wget -q -nd -O /Users/user/path/to/file.html http:\/\/host.com/some_file.html\`;`

Answer (score 1):

use the full path to `wget`, since the daemon doesn't run `.bash_profile`.

```
`/opt/local/bin/wget -q -nd -O /Users/user/path/to/file.html http://host.com/some_file.html`;
```

BTW, there's no need to escape `/` in shell commands.

Answer (score 0):

The backtick operator runs a shell command and returns the output from the shell command.

In this situation, simply logging (or if you have to, echo-ing) the result will probably reveal the error. E.g:

```
$result = `wget -q -nd -O /Users/user/path/to/file.html http:\/\/host.com/some_file.html`;

trigger_error($result, E_USER_NOTICE);
```

Comment: It didn't help, $result is an empty string. I have found the error, please check my comment :)

Comment: If its a path issue $result should be a string containing "sh: wget: command not found"

Comment: Yeah it should, but I do not know why I didn't see any error, though. Maybe because the `sh: wget: command not found` is wrote to the stderr?